# vb.net DataGridView wrong Design Column name after Binding

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

after Visual Studio 2012 CRASH, an error occured in Design,
The Column Name in Design are generated with numbers at end (ex: DataGridViewTextBoxColumn36),
 **NOT with** the ColumName in front like usual (ex: ***FirstNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn***).

I deleted and reBinded multiple times .. Can be an error from Visual Studio ?

*** Update
I created a new project, with a form, BindingSource with Datasource to the same table from db , and is generated ok !.

**UPDATE with SOLUTION !!**
***Thank you @Jorj !! you saved my day ! 

in UserControl.Designer.vb I found duplicates !
 Solution is to delete duplicates from .Designer !***

```
   Friend WithEvents IdDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
   Friend WithEvents FullNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
   Friend WithEvents PhoneDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

   Friend WithEvents DataGridViewTextBoxColumn1 As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
   Friend WithEvents DataGridViewTextBoxColumn2 As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
   Friend WithEvents DataGridViewTextBoxColumn3 As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
```

and a lot of duplicates ..

```
   Friend WithEvents DataGridViewTextBoxColumn52 As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
   Friend WithEvents DataGridViewTextBoxColumn53 As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
```

[image: this is my error]
[image: This is how should be, and in other datagridview works ok]
[image: Here is the DataSource for BindingSource to Patient Entity from Model]

Comment: Is there a Header text property or a .Name value that is "Patient" instead of "PatientName"? I feel like there's a separate field that you should be using. I see no spaces here, so you should be good, but make sure your actual Column name has no spaces since Datagridview can mess with that.

Comment: The class from model is named Patient, and I don't have column names with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it happens after a VS crash: the columns remains defined in yourform.designer.vb so you need to remove those lines.
It happened to me several times:

```
   Friend WithEvents DataGridViewTextBoxColumn20 as System.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
```